# Jquery validation with angular form issue invoking submitHandler callback

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have angular form which works fine until a field becomes visible ,when it's ng-show becomes true ,the jquery validate doesn't call the sumbitHandler callback in single button click (it does in 2 clicks)

Below is the form and the field **someName** becomes visible when href is clicked ,after this there are 2 clicks required to call the submitHandler among other issues.Until the href or if it's clicked again to switch back ,it works fine.

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="some-form"><div class="form-group" ng-show="config.showFormToggle">
            <a href ng-click="toggleOldNew()">{{config.nonDefault === true ? "Switch to Old form" : "Switch to New Form "}} </a>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"  ng-show="config.nonDefault">
            <label for="someName">some Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="someName" name="someName" ng-model="values.someName"  ng-change="update()">
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
        <label for="items">Items</label>
        <input type="text"  id="items" name="items"  ng-model="values.items" ng-change="update()">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right has-spinner" ng-click="callService()">
                <span class="spinner glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span>
                Run
            </button>
        </div>
```

Below is the method called on button click ,it loops over comma separated values in field 1 and creates a TaskRunner and calls it's run method

```
$scope.callService= function (){
          var items = $scope.values.items ?  $scope.values.items.split(/\s*,\s*/) : [];
        items.forEach(function (item) {
       var index=0; 
       //creates a TaskRunner(item.items.length,index) to perform some action on this item ,increment index
         taskRunner.run();
    }
```

}

```
    $scope.createTaskRunner = function (item, total, current) {
      var taskRunner=new TaskRunner({itemToRun:item,totalItem:total,currentItem:current});   
 if(current === 1) {
    runner.validate= function (success) {
                        form.validate({
                            rules: rules,
                            submitHandler: success
                        });

                };
return taskRunner;
 }
```

This starts the task and in this the validate is called which is expected to call the submitHandler

```
 SomeRunner.prototype.run = function () {
                    var self = this;
                    var handler = function () {
                        return self.submitHandler();
                    };

                    if(self.validate) {
                        self.validate(handler);
                    } else {
                        // no validation to be done just call the submit handler
                        handler();
                    }
                };
```

The code is trimmed to be readable.Since the form works in the initial state and does not work in the state when config.nonDefault is true and the someName field becomes visible.In that case it takes 2 clicks for the submitHandler to be called.The first call to validate doesn't call the submitHandler ,when the button is clicked again it does call it.
Is this any known issue with Jquery validation plugin(1.15.1) with Angular(1.2.4) ?

Comment: Why not use the forms built in validation instead of jQuery?  https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: The form itself has state $error, $dirty etc to use your validation. I don't know your use case but it kind of seems like your ignoring Angular, while using Angular.

Comment: @DylanWright you are right ,I just wanted to find out the root cause of this issue.In the validation when i switch to the new form ,the field that becomes visible is required but when in the old form it is not required ,I am not sure if putting 'required' on the field will work.I will check that out

Comment: All the tools you need to achieve your goal are already included in Angular.